# Unicode Encode error when writing to CSV after scraping

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm learning web scraping, and to practice I am trying to scrape a table of Derek Jeter's baseball statistics from baseball-reference.  Using beautifulsoup, I was able to extract the table like so:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2

jeter = "http://www.baseball-reference.com/players/j/jeterde01-bat.shtml"
page = urllib2.urlopen(jeter)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)

table = soup.find('table', id='batting_standard')

#create a list of the header names
tableheaders = table.find_all('th')


headers = []
i = 0
while i < 30:
    headers.append(tableheaders[i].get_text())
    i = i + 1

#map the data points to a json file
data_points = table.find_all('tr', { 'class' : 'full' })
table_rows = []
row_num = 0
for row in data_points:
    cells = row.find_all('td')
    #for each 'tr', assign each 'td' to an entry in the json.
    table_rows.append([])
    for i in range(0, len(cells) - 1):
        table_rows[row_num].append(cells[i].get_text())
    row_num = row_num + 1
```

table_rows ends up being a list, where each element is another list that represents each row of the table:

```
table_rows = [['a','b','c'],['d','e','f']]
```

Then, when I try to write it to a CSV using this code:

import csv

```
with open('/home/russell/Desktop/Python Learning/Web Scraping/jeter.csv', 'wb') as fp:
    a = csv.writer(fp)
    #write the headers for the csv file
    a.writerow(headers) 
    for e in table_rows:
        a.writerow(e)
```

I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/russell/Documents/Python Learning/Web Scraping/jeter_scrape2.py", line 39, in <module>
    a.writerow(e)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 4-5: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I'm new to all of this, so any insights you could provide would be greatly appreciated.

Note: I'm using Python 2.7

**EDIT:**

The line that's hanging it up is this:

```
[u'1998\xa0\u2605', u'24', u'NYY', u'AL', u'149', u'694', u'626', u'127', u'203', u'25', u'8', u'19', u'84', u'30', u'6', u'57', u'119', u'.324', u'.384', u'.481', u'.864', u'127', u'301', u'13', u'5', u'3', u'3', u'1', u'*6']
```

I'm assuming it's the slash in the first item? (u'1998\xa0\u2605').  It is supposed to be a year -- 1998.  The csv writer can process the first few lines, but gets hung up on that one.

Comment: You will need to find the specific row and print the exact contents for us.  Try adding `print e` before `writerow` and tell us what's the last one that prints before the crash.

Comment: Thanks John.  I just added that information.  If you have any insights I'd appreciate it!

Comment: is your csv file supposed to have only characters from the ASCII charset or are you willing to use a wider charset such as UTF-8?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the HTML table you're scraping contains the character U+2605 BLACK STAR.  You can see it clearly on the page next to "1999".  You can easily fix this by simply removing those bits from the first column as you go:

```
for e in table_rows:
    e[0] = e[0].replace(u'\xa0\u2605', u'')
    a.writerow(e)
```

Something like that.

Comment: i ran that, and i'm getting this error: UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xa0 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128).  i did the print(e), and it wasn't able to process any of the rows.

Comment: got it!  thanks a ton for the lead. that first line actually needed to be e[0] = e[0].replace(u''\xa0\u2605', u'')

Comment: @BigRuss: oops, yes I made a little mistake, sorry about that--I will update the answer with your correction.  Glad you got it sorted.

Answer (score 0):

`cvs` module in Python 2 works with bytes. You have to encode Unicode text yourself. Try `writer.writerow([item.encode('utf-8') for item in row])`.